# How can I update MS Word fields based on contents of other fields within the document?

Tags: vba, if-statement, ms-word

I am trying to find a way to lookup and replace contents within an MS Word Doc based on certain content within the same document. I have system generated Word Documents that are one page each in length, but the number of pages can vary from one to 100 (or more). Each document is formatted exactly the same. One phrase with each page of the document (such as "*Type of Charge*" may or may not vary from one page to the next. I need to be able to insert the actual amount of the charge on each page based on the type of charge reflected on that given page.

I was taking the approach of setting bookmark ranges that would be used to search for the phrase, and then setting a bookmark that would indicate where to insert the value. Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub bmAmtDue()
'
' bmAmtDue
'
'
     Dim rng As Range
     Dim iBookmarkSuffix As Integer
     Dim strBookMarkPrefix
    
     strBookMarkPrefix = "BM"
    
     Set rng = ActiveDocument.Range
     With rng.Find
        .Text = "Please see fee chart, with additional requirements, on reverse side"
        Do While .Execute
            rng.Text = "" 'clear the "XXX" (optional)
            iBookmarkSuffix = iBookmarkSuffix + 1
            ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add strBookMarkPrefix & iBookmarkSuffix, rng
        Loop
    End With

End Sub


Sub bmStartPermitType()
'
' bmStartPermitType
'
'
     Dim rng2 As Range
     Dim iBookmarkSuffix As Integer
     Dim strBookMarkPrefix
    
     strBookMarkPrefix = "BMStartPermitType"
    
     Set rng = ActiveDocument.Range
     With rng.Find
        .Text = "Type:"
        Do While .Execute
            iBookmarkSuffix = iBookmarkSuffix + 1
            ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add strBookMarkPrefix & iBookmarkSuffix, rng
        Loop
    End With

End Sub


Sub bmEndPermitType()
'
' bmEndPermitType
'
'
     Dim rng2 As Range
     Dim iBookmarkSuffix As Integer
     Dim strBookMarkPrefix
    
     strBookMarkPrefix = "BMEndPermitType"
    
     Set rng = ActiveDocument.Range
     With rng.Find
        .Text = "Amount due:"
        Do While .Execute
            iBookmarkSuffix = iBookmarkSuffix + 1
            ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add strBookMarkPrefix & iBookmarkSuffix, rng
        Loop
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Bookmarks are OK, but might be "too flexible" - They can even start in the middle of a table cell and end in a the middle of another paragraph. I suggest you to try doing it with Content Controls - their appearance might also be more suitable for your scenario. Check this [link](http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/insert_content_with_content_controls.html).

If you can write a simple .NET application, there is [mail merge toolkit](http://www.docentric.com) that will make your task much more easy. It will allow you to create word document that will act as a template (it also uses Content Controls for tagging) which you will be able to populate with data from your .NET application. And it demands only couple of lines of code to write.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I really know nothing about writing .NET.  I think that I will abandon the bookmark approach.  I am going to try using VBA to search for keywords, store the content adjacent to the keyword as a variable, and use the vlookup function to retrieve the value from Excel and write it to the Word Doc.  If I get it to work, I will post my code for anyone to use who may have a need for it.